# How to find contigious elements in a 2D array using C

Tags: c, arrays

I am having a 2D array of `land=0` and `water=1`. I have made a logic to get the maximum available land i.e maximum contiguous land bits available in the 2D array. However, when I use that logic on paper it is giving correct answer but on system it is not giving correct answer.

Say array `Array[3][9]` is having elements :

```
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1   
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0   
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
```

In the below code Array is input2.

The output should be 10.

The logic which I have developed is

```
int countContigious(char* array[],int x,int y,int row1,int col1)
{
if(x<0||x>=row1||y<0||y>=col1||array[x][y]!=0)
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    array[x][y]=2;
    return 1+countContigious(array,x-1,y,row1,col1)+countContigious(array,x+1,y,row1,col1)+countContigious(array,x,y-1,row1,col1)+countContigious(array,x,y+1,row1,col1);
}
} 
int largestSize(int input1[],char* input2[])
{
int row,col,i,j;
int count=0;
int result=0;
row=input1[0];
col=input1[1];
for(i=0;i<row;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<col;j++)
    {
        if(input2[i][j]==0)
        {
            count=countContigious(input2,i,j,row,col);
            if(count>result)
            {
                result=count;
            }
        }
    }
}
return result;
}
```

According to me it should return answer in variable result. Can anyone tell what is wrong in my logic?

Comment: you really should try to look at this with a debugger, it is hard to tell what might be the problem, as your variable names are not very descriptive either

Comment: I count 9 as the most continuous land, unless you count diagonals

Comment: May I suggest that you include the code that creates your 2D "array" - since you actually create an array of arrays rather than a static 2D array. It's important to show how you did that - it might contain a bug, and it is needed for anyone to run your code.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus - I count 10 contiguous zeros. 3 in the first row, 5 in the second, 2 in the third.

Comment: Derp, was counting 1s

Comment: Since `input2` is of type `char`, shouldn't condition be `input2[x][y]!='0'`?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a service for debugging your buggy program. Here's some good advice on how to find your own bugs. You are already simulating it on paper, which is a great start. Now compare your paper algorithm to the *actual behaviour* of your real algorithm using a debugger; where they differ is where you'll find the bug. http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @GoldRoger - it depends on whether the array was filled with `'0'` and `'1'` or with `0` and `1`. Based on the fact that a "visited" location gets set to `2` (not `'2'`) I think that OP is using `0` and `1`.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787/are-there-legitimate-fix-my-code-questions/253788#253788

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 2D array. The usual way to traverse it, is be double for loop.
The usual order will be this:
1st row - 1st column
1st row - 2nd column
..
1st row - last column
2nd row - 1st column
...
last row - last column

Assume you are using the order described above, you may want to do something like this:

Every time you find a land bit, explore the array at the right, upper, right-upper, right-bottom and at the bottom of this position (the other directions are visited before this step) and find the max length of contigius zeros.

Here is very naive example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  const int N = 4;
  const int M = 5;

  int a[4][5] =
  {
    { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
    { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
  };

  /* A naive implementation, which can optimized.
   * Some initializations are not needed.
   */

  int i, j, k, z, len;
  int max_len = -1;

  // traverse the array in the order described before
  for(i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i)
  {
    for(j = 0 ; j < M ; ++j)
    {
      /* Land bit found! Explore the array in the needed directions. */
      if(a[i][j] == 0) {

        // remember where we start from
        k = i;
        z = j;
        len = 0;
        // search right
        // while we are inside the limits of the array
        // (here we need to check only the columns, since
        // we move to the right)
        while(z < M) {
          // and we find land bits
          if(a[k][z++] == 0)
            len++; // increase the current length
          else     // we want contiguous land bits
            break; // we found a water bit, so break this loop
        }

        // is the current length better than the current found?
        if(len > max_len)
          max_len = len; // yes, so update max_len


        // return back to initial cell we started from
        k = i;
        z = j;
        len = 0;
        // search down
        while(k < N) {
          if(a[k++][z] == 0)
            len++;
          else
            break;
        }
        if(len > max_len)
          max_len = len;

        k = i;
        z = j;
        len = 0;
        // search right and down
        while(k < N && z < M) {
          if(a[k++][z++] == 0)
            len++;
          else
            break;
        }
        if(len > max_len)
          max_len = len;

        k = i;
        z = j;
        len = 0;
        // search upper
        while(k >= 0) {
          if(a[k--][z] == 0)
            len++;
          else
            break;
        }
        if(len > max_len)
          max_len = len;

        k = i;
        z = j;
        len = 0;
        // search upper and right
        while(k >= 0 && z < M) {
          if(a[k++][z++] == 0)
            len++;
          else
            break;
        }
        if(len > max_len)
          max_len = len;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("max_length = %d\n", max_len);

  return 0;
}
```

After understanding the naive approach, try to see where your approach misses. Use a paper and try with smaller examples. This site is not just for debugging. :)

[EDIT]

As Floris mentioned, this example assumes that the land is a straight line, in any direction.

Based on the answer of Floris, in order to get it work for the U shaped land, you need to modify your `countC` like this:

```
else
{
    input2[x][y]=2;
    return 1+countC(input2,x-1,y,r1,c1)+
        countC(input2,x+1,y,r1,c1)+
        countC(input2,x,y-1,r1,c1)+
        countC(input2,x,y+1,r1,c1)+
        countC(input2,x+1,y+1,r1,c1)+
        countC(input2,x+1,y-1,r1,c1)+
        countC(input2,x-1,y+1,r1,c1)+
        countC(input2,x-1,y-1,r1,c1);
}
```

as you can see, you would need to go into diagonals too.

Comment: Thanks for this program but my logic was similar to this one based on recursion. After checking this program also I got same answer so I think there is some problem with the compiler.

Comment: @user3612714, I am not saying that a problem with the installation of your compiler may exist (or even a bug in the compiler), but the chances are, that I  or you have a bug. Can you explain what are you getting? :)

Comment: well answer should be `10` but I am getting `1` :)

Comment: In which example? In the example I provided, the answer should be 5!

Comment: No, not with your array but with the one in my asked question `array[3][9]`. :)

Comment: It is not clear to me how this answers the question.

Comment: @Floris I was asking whether there is any wrong in my logic and after reading this naive example I got my answer. :)

Comment: I don't think that this logic would work for a U shaped piece of land.

Comment: @Floris So, which logic would work on that type of piece of land, what you suggest?

Comment: @Floris, good catch! My example assumes that the land is a straight line.

Comment: @user3612714 - your original logic works fine on U shaped land - see my updated answer (although I did not show it in my answer with U shaped land in the example, I did test it and it did work).

Comment: @Floris, no it will not. Maybe you pasted the wrong code.

Comment: @user3612714, make sure to read Floris's answer too and then see in my edited answer what you should do, in order to get the code to work for all the shapes!

Answer (score 0):

Your code as written *can* be part of a working program - in other words, your logic is correct. I suspect that your problem is in "the code you didn't show". To demonstrate, I have taken your code and turned it into a complete working program - without changing your code at all.

Note though that you are doing something potentially dangerous where you write

```
if(x<0||x>=r1||y<0||y>=c1||input2[x][y]!=0)
```

Since the compiler "short circuits" the OR statement, you never evaluation `input2[x][y]` when either of the indices are out of bounds - but I don't think that is behavior you ought to count on. It would be safer to test for boundaries first, and return `0` for "out of bounds"; then test for non-zero value for the location (which is now a "valid" location) in a separate `if` statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int countC(char* input2[],int x,int y,int r1,int c1)
{

if(x<0||x>=r1||y<0||y>=c1||input2[x][y]!=0) // <<<< dangerous! better have two ifs >>>>
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    input2[x][y]=2;
    return 1+countC(input2,x-1,y,r1,c1)+countC(input2,x+1,y,r1,c1)+countC(input2,x,y-1,r1,c1)+countC(input2,x,y+1,r1,c1);
}
}
int largestSize(int input1[],char* input2[])
{
int r,c,i,j;
int count=0;
int result=0;
r=input1[0];
c=input1[1];
for(i=0;i<r;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    {
        if(input2[i][j]==0)
        {
            count=countC(input2,i,j,r,c);
            if(count>result)
            {
                result=count;
            }
        }
    }
}
return result;
}

// <<< new function added to create a "variable size 2D array"
char **twoDchar(int rc, int cc) {
  char** p;
  int ii;
  p = malloc(rc * sizeof (char*));
  p[0]=malloc(rc * cc * sizeof(char));
  for(ii=1; ii<rc; ii++) {
    p[ii]=p[0]+ii*cc*sizeof(char);
  }
  return p;
}

// <<< added main() function to test the code >>>

int main(void) {
  int dims[]={3,9};
  char land[3][9]={ \
    {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, \
    {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, \
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}};

  char** lp;
  int ii, jj;
  lp = twoDchar(3,9);
  for(ii=0;ii<3;ii++)
    for(jj=0;jj<9;jj++) {
      lp[ii][jj]=land[ii][jj];
    }
  printf("biggest mass is %d\n", largestSize(dims,lp));
}
```

When I run the above, I do indeed get the answer `10`.

**update** for an example of "U shaped land":

```
  char land[3][9]={\
    {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},\
    {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},\
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}};
```

I get the answer `9` as expected.

**note** the comment I made when the question first appeared:

> May I suggest that you include the code that creates your 2D "array" -
>   since you actually create an array of arrays rather than a static 2D
>   array. It's important to show how you did that - it might contain a
>   bug, and it is needed for anyone to run your code.

Now that I took a closer look, it does appear like that might indeed have been the source of the problem (although you never did show how you came up with your 2D array).

Comment: actually someone here asked me to make my variables a little more descriptive so while I was replacing my variables names here I forgot to change them in these places but in actual code row1 is r1 and col1 is c1.

Comment: This won't work for a U shaped land. Try with all ones six zeros in a V shape. :/

Comment: I fixed the logical bug, see my answer! I believe, this was a team job. :)

Comment: @G.Samaras It is not supposed to connect diagonals.

Comment: I do not see where diagonals are out of play in the question (maybe its somewhere in the comments). If this is the case, then yes, this will work. In my updated answer, the recursive approach should return 11 for your U example. :)

Comment: @G.Samaras - I conclude this from the fact that the correct answer for the original land was stated to be `10`, not `12`.

Comment: Correct! But it wasn't stated. The good thing is that the OP got his answer. :)